# Leaning with Player Controller

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm adding leaning to my player controller and I can't find out how to stop the rotation overriding the tilt

```
  void Look() {
      transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity);

      verticalLookRotation += Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
      verticalLookRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalLookRotation, -90f, 90f);

      cameraHolder.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.left * verticalLookRotation;
  
  }

  void TiltCamera(float angle) {
      cameraHolder.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution add a second game object to parent the camera holder game object